# Using ArcGIS Tokens to visualize user authenticated data in Esri Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-leaflet

I'm currently using Esri Leaflet with authenticated user services. Authenticated services are set up and work fine for displaying geographic data after login, however, I want to  create a dashboard and visualizations (mostly graphs) from the data in the SDE within our mapping platform. eg."Your trends over time vs all users trends over time". I can export the data as csvs from our database and use D3, however I'm really stuck on a more efficient way to do this using authenticated layers.

Is there a way to create visualizations while using an esri token to get the user-specific data? Additionally, I want to aggregate all data to display as well (from other users) but I am concerned about security. Eg. A graph of User A's submissions vs all submissions by  all users (user b, user c) without user b and user c's data being exposed to user A.

I can't find any working examples of this. I'm mostly concerned about security I do not want our users to be able to see other user's data (unless aggregated).

I've seen one similar unanswered question at [Seeking data visualization techniques for web maps using Esri and open source suites?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69702). This [question addresses](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168998/leaflet-click-feature-to-get-external-diagram?rq=1) the D3 aspects but not authentication or querying the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a sample which utilizes an [OAuth](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/core-concepts/security-and-authentication/browser-based-user-logins/) workflow to allow users to sign in and access secure content from ArcGIS Online/Portal here:
http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/arcgis-online-auth.html

You can find an example for requesting a token from ArcGIS Server here:
http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/arcgis-server-auth.html

Comment: Thanks John, I've gotten that far. What I want is to be able to access the data for plotting in D3 based on the username, or a process to get the username and extract the data from the service to run a script to create plots.

Comment: okay. thats not a leaflet or esri leaflet question but the generic process is the same.  you need to assist the user request a token and then you need to pass it through when making requests to query the data you intend on plotting.